# Cron expression to run from 8PM to 6 AM

Tags: java, spring, cron

I am trying to write a cron expression for spring @Scheduled annotation that should be executed on the interval of 10 minutes between 8 PM to 6 AM  -

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */10 20-06 * * MON-FRI", zone = "America/New_York")
```

However above cron is giving 'Invalid inverted range' exception. When I try

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */10 20-23,0-6 * * MON-FRI", zone = "America/New_York")
```

then it does not run between 23 and 0.
Is there any way to write a cron expression that can cover 23 to 0 hours also.

Comment: Have you tried this page: http://www.cronmaker.com Maybe it can help you generating the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

use below it should run from 8 PM to 6 AM

```
*/10 20,0-6 * * MON-FRI    (min hour day month week)
```

above expression translates to -

> At every 10th minute past hour 20 and every hour from 0 through 6 on
> every day-of-week from Monday through Friday

Comment: This is wrong. It's supposed to execute at 9PM - midnight too.

Answer (score -1):

I would expect your 2nd example to work. Not sure whether that's a bug in Spring's implementation. Seems like it.

It's very long-winded, but you could always just enumerate the entire list of values.

```
... 20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6 ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally I found that ..20-22,23,0-6.. works fine